Issues setting up Selenium server with PHP
I'm trying (as suggested by someone in my previous question) to set up Selenium Server standalone with php-webdriver, in order to get started with scraping a page behind a form
I'm following this guide:
https://www.zenrows.com/blog/selenium-php
I did all the steps listed, and also copied the code for testing purpose. My first doubt comes when I get this
INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 8 available processors
INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Firefox for {"browserName": "firefox","platformName": "Windows 11"} 8 times
INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Chrome for {"browserName": "chrome","platformName": "Windows 11"} 8 times
INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Edge for {"browserName": "MicrosoftEdge","platformName": "Windows 11"} 8 times
INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Internet Explorer for {"browserName": "internet explorer","platformName": "Windows 11"} 1 times
INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative
INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node 8562f610-78a1-49b3-946c-688f53b66fe9 (uri: http://192.168.1.30:4444) from DOWN to UP
INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node 8562f610-78a1-49b3-946c-688f53b66fe9 at http://192.168.1.30:4444. Health check every 120s
INFO [Standalone.execute] - Started Selenium Standalone 4.16.1 (revision 9b4c83354e): http://192.168.1.30:4444


The command prompt doesn't return to receive more input, is this normal or I should give it more time?
Aside from this, executing the scraper.php file with php src/scraper.php gives the following error, and none of the things I read online seemed to help.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\Internal\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless"]}}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 4444 after 0 ms: Connection refused in /home/b2badmin2/php-selenium-project/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/Internal/WebDriverCurlException.php:20

Am I missing something? How can I make this work as in the guide linked?
